# DAX: Calculate only when data is present for all years in dataset

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a data set that contains sales forecast data by year over 5 years.

Each row has customer, item type, year, qty and sales price.

Not all customers buy all products in all years.

I want to get a list of all products that are purchased in **all** of the listed years.

An example, cut-down table looks like this:

```
Customer    Product Year    Qty Price
CustA       ProdA   2020    50  100
CustA       ProdA   2021    50  100
CustA       ProdA   2022    50  100
CustA       ProdB   2020    50  100
CustA       ProdB   2021    50  100
CustA       ProdC   2021    50  100
CustA       ProdC   2022    50  100
CustA       ProdD   2020    50  100
CustA       ProdD   2021    50  100
CustA       ProdD   2022    50  100
CustB       ProdA   2021    50  100
CustB       ProdA   2022    50  100
CustB       ProdC   2020    50  100
CustB       ProdC   2021    50  100
CustB       ProdC   2022    50  100
CustB       ProdD   2020    50  100
CustB       ProdD   2021    0   100
CustB       ProdD   2022    50  100
```

And transposed, looks like this:

```
Customer    Product     2020    2021    2022
CustA       ProdA       50      50      50
CustA       ProdB       50      50
CustA       ProdC               50      50
CustA       ProdD       50      50      50
CustB       ProdA               50      50
CustB       ProdC       50      50      50
CustB       ProdD       50      0       50
```

So, for this example, I'd want to do calculations on, or indicate rows that have a sales qty for all three years.  I was trying to use the following formula which I would have compared with the max number of years in the set to mark a row as valid or not, but it's killing Excel. There are only 32,000 rows in the source table.

```
=CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT(DataTable[Year]), 
      filter(DataTable, DataTable[Product] = EARLIER(DataTable[Product])), 
      filter(DataTable, DataTable[Customer] = EARLIER(DataTable[Customer])), 
      filter(DataTable, DataTable[Qty] > 0)
    )
```

Is there a better approach I could use for this?

Comment: Does the customer matter here? That is, does it matter which customer purchased a product or just that the product was purchased in that year?

Comment: It just needs to indicate any row where a purchase is made in all years.  So the DAX code I provided, I expected to give me a new column with the number of years the sale was made.  I'd then be able to use any entry where this value was 3 (in this example)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You're looking to get a list of products purchased in all years. My question is if it counts if any customer purchases it or if it needs to be all customers and all years.

Comment: The customer doesn't matter, just that the part was (will be) purchased in all years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
ProductList =
VAR AllYears = DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'DataTable'[Year] )
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'DataTable',
        'DataTable'[Product],
        "YearsPurchased", CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'DataTable'[Year] ),
           'DataTable'[Qty] > 0
        )
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( Summary, [YearsPurchased] = AllYears ),
        "Product", [Product]
    )
```

The `Summary` aggregates at the `Product` level and looks at how many distinct years it had with non-zero quantity. Then you just filter for the ones that match `AllYears` and take the `Product` column.

---

Note that this returns a single column table and thus doesn't work as a calculated column or measure but a list is what you asked for.

**Edit:** To get the `YearsPurchased` as a calculated column, you just need part of this:

```
YearsPurchased =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'DataTable'[Year] ),
    FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( 'DataTable', 'DataTable'[Product] ), 'DataTable'[Qty] > 0 )
)
```

Comment: Yes, I see what you've done, thanks.  I also see how poor I am at asking accurate questions!  Can this be amended to be a calculated column (e.g. containing the number of years where there were sales)?

Comment: Aww man, I had a bad day yesterday....you asked if customer was important and I said no.  Looking back, I should have said yes.  My question should have been "How can I create a calculated column that shows the number of years that each part was sold to each customer"?  Apologies for the glaring omission!

Comment: So using your suggestion as a baseline, I assume I can just add Customer to the ALLEXCEPT filter?

Comment: Your answer led me to a suitable solution so I've marked as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use dax to achieve this. Create a matrix visualization using the needed data.
It should looks like this:

[image]

Remember to disable the total and subtotal options.

This is other solution using a new column so you dont have to expand the matrix.

```
Column = COMBINEVALUES( " ", Table[Customer], Table[Product] )
```

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Maybe I've phrased my question inaccurately but it's not the matrix that I'm trying to achieve; I want to use data from the table only where there is data for all three years present.  So, for example, I could add another column to the matrix table called, say UseThis, and would have TRUE for rows 1, 4 & 6 and FALSE for the others.

Comment: My apologies, i will update my answer with the right solution.